# grid horizontal view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik

i had a list of one column table that i want to be displayed in horizontal view 'besides each other';

what is the best way to do that?
and if i using Telerik controls, any links to sample code or tutorials will be helpful.

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/pivot/defaultcs.aspx

If you have a single column then the column name would appear on the left and each individual "row" or item of your data would appear as a column in the gridview